# Flutter doctor doesn't always run

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

Im on Linux mint and have installed flutter. At first when I installed, it was working fine. But, when my system restarted I was getting error `bash: flutter: command not found`. So I came across solutions here on StackOverflow and was able to rectify the issue by setting `$PATH` variable. But when my system was shut back down and up again, I was getting the same error.

Are there any permanent solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.bashrc` file if you're using `bash` shell or `.zshrc` file if you're using `zsh` shell.

You can find `.bashrc` file in your user root directory `~/.bashrc`. Create the one if you don't have one and add the path in `.bashrc` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/flutter/path/location
```

After adding it source the `.bashrc` file.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Well, ,I did as you said and added the flutter/bin to the path and ran source on the bashrc file. But no luck. Got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to export your Path?. Try them both, `.bashrc` didn't work for me, but the profile did.